# How to observe label content?

Tags: c#, wpf, binding, label, contentobserver

I have 3 fields in my TimeEntry window:

- StartTime
- EndTime
- Length (double - hours)

All controls have binding to one object.

I've implemented System.ComponentModel.INotifyPropertyChanged in model class,
and I have already updating content in label with changes on start or end time, but..

I have to observe changes to block modifications which will create length below 0.

How should I do this?

Comment: Just to be sure. You want to execute some method when the text in the label changes?

Answer (score 0):

You could implement this logic in your model class

```
public class MyModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
  ...
    public DateTime StartTime
    {
        get { return _startTime; }
        set 
        {
             if ((EndTime - value).TotalMinutes >= 0) // only allow changes if it doesn't result in < 0 timespan.
             {
                 _startTime = value;
                 OnPropertyChanged("StartTime", "Length");
             }
        }
    }

    public DateTime EndTime
    {
        get { return _endTime; }
        set 
        {
             if ((value - StartTime).TotalMinutes >= 0) 
             {
                 _endTime = value;
                 OnPropertyChanged("EndTime", "Length");
             }
        }
    }

    public double Length
    {
         get { return (EndTime - StartTime).TotalMinutes / 60.0; }           
    }
  ...
}
```